# Windows XP bug, or Virus? Text moves from "All or part of file name" field to the "A word or phrase in the file" field

Tags: windows, windows-xp, virus, windows-search, trojan

This would be too big a bug to not be on Google, one would think.

Repeatable problem. (click) Start -> (click) Search -> (click) Pictures, Music, or Video -> (check) Pictures and Photos -> (type text: testing) All or part of the file name -> (click) Use advanced search options -> !! "testing" has now been moved from the "All or part of file name" field to the "A word or phrase in the file" field." !! This happens every time. (I finally stepped through this as my image searches kept searching inside of files instead of for matching file names. I thought at first I kept putting it in the wrong field, but I couldn't have been, as that field hadn't even appeared yet.)

Windows XP SP3 w/all updates (updating is enabled).

Comment: Because it's an advanced search. It searches for more than just filenames, now you have the ability to search through the file itself... the field changes, so it doesn't tranfer the text over because it might not be what you are looking for. I would call this a feature.

Comment: @Ekaj - does this happen on your XP system?  Please test it.  Advanced search adds more options, it should not change the existing criteria you specified of the file name you are looking form.

Comment: You typed "text:" at the begining, which instructs Windows to search for the text "testing" inside documents, it's doing what you told it to.

Comment: @techie007 - Please step through this on your XP system.  Does it do the same thing?  ---  //which instructs Windows// - No, the first field displayed says, "All or part of file name" - and that's the field I filled out.  When I click on advanced so I can select the drive/directory, my text is then moved from the "All or part of file name" field to the "A word or phrase in the file" field" - which is a VERY slow search, as it is search the contents of every image file.  When I use advanced (to set a directory), I have to delete the text and put it back in the file name field where it belongs.

Comment: Have you got the "Windows Desktop Search" update/add-on installed in XP?

Comment: @techie007 - The Google links to "Windows Desktop Search" all end up at "Windows Search 4.0" at Microsoft, which I have not installed.  (I have indexing turned off as it slows the computer, so I didn't bother with that optional update.)

Comment: Good to know -- that thing is annoying. Unfortunately I can't get at my XP VM right now. :/